# gallery script - filetypes more than just: jpg

Tags: php, jpeg, gallery

I have this script. It is part of my gallery script. Following code is a *.php file where image being processed while uploading. Can anyone help me how to change this code to version where user will be able to upload not only jpg files but png, gif etc. too?

```
if (!defined('InGallery')) exit('Access denied');

class Image {
    public $ImageId = null;
    public $Name = null;
    public $Details = null;
    public $Date = null;

    private $_Elements = array();
    private $_Comments = array();

    function __construct($id) {      
        try {
            if (is_int($id)) {
                $this->ImageId = $id;
                /** @var PDO */
                global $Connection;
                $query = $Connection->prepare("SELECT Name, Details, Date FROM gall_images WHERE ImageId = :id");
                $query->bindValue(":id", $this->ImageId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query->execute();
                $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $query->closeCursor();

                $this->Name = $result['Name'];
                $this->Details = $result['Details'];
                $this->Date = $result['Date']; 
            }
            else if (is_array($id)) {
                $this->Name = $id['Name'];
                $this->Details = $id['Details'];
                $this->Date = time(); 
            }       
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo "[ERROR]Connection to the database.";
        }
    }

    function GetThumb() {
        return PATH."/images/thumbs/{$this->ImageId}.jpg";
    }

    function GetOriginal() {
        return PATH."/images/full/{$this->ImageId}.jpg";
    }

    function GetDate() {
        return date('d-m-Y H:i', $this->Date);
    }

    function GetComments() {
        try {
            include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/class_comment.php';
            /** @var PDO */
            global $Connection;
            $query = $Connection->prepare("SELECT CommentId FROM gall_comments WHERE ImageId = :id ORDER BY Date DESC");
            $query->bindValue(":id", $this->ImageId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();          

            foreach ($query as $value) {
                $this->_Comments[] = new Comment((int)$value['CommentId']);
            }

            $query->closeCursor();
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo "[ERROR]Comments error.";
        }

        return $this->_Comments;
    }

    function GetElements() {
        try {
            include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/class_element.php';
            /** @var PDO */
            global $Connection;
            $query = $Connection->prepare("SELECT ElementId FROM gall_elements WHERE ImageId = :id ORDER BY gall_elements.Order");
            $query->bindValue(":id", $this->ImageId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();          

            foreach ($query as $value) {
                $this->_Elements[] = new Element((int)$value['ElementId']);
            }

            $query->closeCursor();
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo "[ERROR]Elements error.";
        }

        return $this->_Elements;
    }

    function Modify() {
        try {
            include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/class_element.php';
            /** @var PDO */
            global $Connection;
            $query = $Connection->prepare("UPDATE gall_images SET Name = :Name, Details = :Details, Date = :Date WHERE ImageId = :ImageId");

            $query->bindValue(":Name", $this->Name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(":Details", $this->Details, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(":Date", $this->Date, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindValue(":ImageId", $this->ImageId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();
            $query->closeCursor();

            return 1;
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo "[ERROR]Elements error.";
        }
    }

    function Remove() {
        try {
            foreach ($this->GetComments() as $value) {
                $value->Remove();
            }

            foreach ($this->GetElements() as $value) {
                $value->Remove();
            }

            /** @var PDO */
            global $Connection;
            $query = $Connection->prepare("DELETE FROM gall_images WHERE ImageId = :ImageId");
            $query->bindValue(":ImageId", $this->ImageId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();
            $query->closeCursor();

            $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/full/'.$this->ImageId.'.jpg';
            $pathThumbs = dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/thumbs/'.$this->ImageId.'.jpg';
            @unlink($path);
            @unlink($pathThumbs);

            return 1;
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo "[ERROR]Remove";
        }
    }

    function Add() {
        try {      
            /** @var PDO */
            global $Connection;
            $query = $Connection->prepare("INSERT INTO gall_images VALUES(NULL, :Name, :Details, :Date)");
            $query->bindValue(":Name", $this->Name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(":Details", $this->Details, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(":Date", $this->Date, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();
            $this->ImageId = $Connection->lastInsertId();
            $query->closeCursor();

            return 1;
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo "[ERROR]Add";
        }
    }

    function CreateThumb() {
        $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/full/'.$this->ImageId.'.jpg';
        $pathThumbs = dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/thumbs/'.$this->ImageId.'.jpg';
        if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {      
            $info = pathinfo($path);
            if (strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg') {
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
                $width = imagesx($img);
                $height = imagesy($img);

                $max_width = 170;
                $max_height = 215;

                $scale = max($max_width/$width, $max_height/$height);

                $new_width  = ceil($scale*$width);
                $new_height = ceil($scale*$height);


                //$new_width = $ThumbWidth;
                //$new_height = floor($height * ( $new_width / $width ));

                $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
                imagejpeg($tmp_img, $pathThumbs);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Cannot load image {$this->_ImageName}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I count at least 4 places that need to be changed from `.jpg` to allow for other file types. So which one are you struggling with? If all, then this is too broad for SO, as we are not a code writing service. You can hire/pay someone to do that. You need to narrow your issue down to the one you are working on / struggling with.

Comment: The broblem is that my PHP programmer made this sh*** and he wrote this code including only jpg extension. I'am sooo angry! And now he said that he can't modified this because he... don't know how:/ So I try to change this be myself. I'am a graphic designer and I know only basics in PHP :/ I changed:if (strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg') { to this --->
    if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' || strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpeg' || strtolower($info['extension']) == 'png' || strtolower($info['extension']) == 'gif') {